How to play audio and record simultaneously without capturing playback in AVAudioRecorder on iOS?
I'm developing an iOS app where I need to play an audio file while recording from the microphone. However, I want to prevent the playback audio from being captured in the recording, but currently, the recorded audio includes the playback output as well.
What I have tried:
Audio Session Configuration:
I used AVAudioSession with .playAndRecord mode and enabled .mixWithOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, and .allowBluetooth options.
This setup lets me play and record simultaneously but doesn’t prevent the playback sound from being picked up in the recording.
Using Headphones:
Using headphones helps reduce feedback, but it’s not a complete solution for all cases since some users may still use the device speakers.
Sample Code:
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try? session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .mixWithOthers])

Is there a recommended way to configure AVAudioSession or AVAudioRecorder to isolate the recording input from the playback output? Ideally, I'd like a solution that doesn’t rely on using external hardware like headphones.
Any advice or workaround would be greatly appreciated!

In the most general case, this isn't possible. Removing echo is a complex and imprecise science. The sounds coming back to the microphone is not precisely the sound that left the speaker. It is delayed by an arbitrary amount due to reflections, and there may be multiple reflections that interact. The tool that attempts to solve this as best it can is called AEC (acoustic echo cancellation).
You've included .mixWithOthers suggesting you're trying to cancel echo on audio your app is not producing. That makes handling the situation in your app impossible as well, since you cannot access audio generated by other apps. If you did not do this, then you could apply echo cancellation yourself (complicated, but possible).
That means you have to rely on the OS. Apple does provide some modes that can help. For example, I would experiment specifically with the .voiceChat mode which enables VoiceProcessingIO (which includes AEC).
I would also explore moving to AVCaptureSession, which is a bit more configurable, but I wouldn't assume it will necessarily fix the problem.

Hi Rob, Thanks for your advised. I'll do some experiment for these two feature and try to make so improvement for better recording quality when playing.
